# Hierarchical order of newly created relations in Third Normal Form (3NF)

Tags: relational-database, entity-relationship, database-normalization

I have one relation named `EMPLOYEE`, and I am tasked with converting it into the Third Normal Form (3NF). It has multiple attributes, but for the sake of this question we are only interested in:

```
 emp_no     (employee number)
 office_no  (office number)
 dep_no     (department number)
 proj_no    (project number)
```

I know that in third normal form, the primary key can be the **only** determinant for the non-key attributes in the same relation, and in the question it states that the above listed attributes must be **globally unique**. Thus, I am assuming that I would create a new relation for each of these attributes.

But, this is where I am confused. When I create a new relation, I set the corresponding attribute as a foreign key in the old relation, and the primary key of the new one, right?

Also some other things:

1. Does the order in which I do this in matter? For example, I could have the `EMPLOYEE` relation reference the new relation for `OFFICE`, and then have that reference the new `DEPARTMENT` relation... however, I could *also* have it go `EMPLOYEE->DEPARTMENT->OFFICE`. The business rules do state that each employee can only belong to one department, and each department can only belong to one office.
2. Am I right in assuming that in third normal form, I cannot have `emp_no` along with any of the other above attributes if they are not part of the primary key? My reasoning for this is because you *could* determine (for example) phone number if you knew the office number by traversing through the foreign/primary key pairs of each relation.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1) Yes. Your example models the business rule **Employee -> Office -> Department** rather than **Employee -> Department -> Office**. (2) Uh? What is the second question.

Comment: *"I know that in third normal form, the primary key can be the only determinant for the non-key attributes in the same relation..."* No. *Every* candidate key--not just the primary key--is a determinant for every non-key attribute.

Comment: Pieter, I simply meant that if for example you can derive Department in **any** number of steps from Project, then you cannot have them in the same relation, correct?

Mike, you're correct, but what I meant is that essentially when you are finished, the only attribute which should determine the values of the non-key attributes is the candidate key that will in all likely-hood become the primary key... am I right in assuming this?

Comment: @araisbec: No. You need to know all the candidate keys before you *start* trying to improve the structure of a table. For example, how you can possibly *identify* a partial key dependency--something that you must *remove* to reach 2NF--if you don't know every candidate key?